# How does an image stay in place with button on it (responsiveness)?

Tags: html, css, responsiveness

Do you know a way how an image stays in place when I zoom in / out the window?

The problem is that if I zoom out the window horizontally, my image stays, but if I do it vertically then my image automatically gets smaller.
The image should stay in place, because there is a button on it, which also should stay in place on the image.

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.img-responsive {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 55%;
}

.pic {
  margin-right: -170px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: -14px;
}

.img-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-overlay:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 40%;
}

.bird {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 61%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="img-wrapper text-center">
      <img class="img-responsive bird" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png">
      <div class="img-overlay">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pic" id="birdbird">click!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to to display all the image width in responsive ?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please move your HTML and CSS into a parseable snippet aswell as use direct pathes to images or placehodlers.

Comment: also are you using a framework such as bootstrap?  if so please label the question as such.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the image staying in place. Is the button to always be over the exact same part of the image, whatever happens to the viewport size?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the image in responsive properly in **Bootstrap**, you only change `img-responsive` image class to be **`img-fluid`**, and it 'll work.